# Windows sometimes does not open fully

Tags: 11.04, unity, display

I am using natty unity. I am facing 1 intermittent problem. Sometimes, my application windows does not open completely. For example, please refer following image.
[image]

You may observe that my google chrome has opened two tabs whereas my firefox (Facebook tab) is running behind in the background. In such case, I am not able to operate on chrome. I have to minimize all open windows and then reopen google chrome. Please refer following image.
[image]

Any pointers to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried dragging chrome (or any new window) towards status/task bar? it automatically maximizes the window (if that is the issue)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known and *very* annoying bug, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/772612

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `compiz --replace`. That usually fixes those small glitches. But to truly fix the problem, you should file a bug on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net).

Answer (score 0):

I've notived that I seem to have this problem with apps that have custom drawn windows (ie. the title bar is not standard).

For Google Chrome you can get rid of the custom title bar. In preferences search for GTK in the left side search bar and select "Use system title bar and borders".